# Getting cart products link and image in shortcode in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code which lists the products added to cart via shortcode. However, these are only the titles. I need help in getting the products URL so the titles are hyperlinks to each product. Also, I would like to display the image of the product in front of the title. Thanks for your help and your time.

Code I currently have:

```
// Add Shortcode [bag_products]
function get_cart_products() {
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
 foreach( $cart as $cart_item ){
$product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
   $cart_items .= '&ndash;&nbsp;'.$cart_item['data']->get_title().'<br>';
 }
 return $cart_items;
}
add_shortcode( 'bag_products', 'get_cart_products' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output a list you can then style as you like.  The function get_image() returns the 'shop_thumbnail' size by default.

```
function get_cart_products() {

    $bag_products = '<ul>';

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        $bag_products .= '<li>'. $product->get_image() .'<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product->get_title() . '</a></li>';
    }

    $bag_products .= '</ul>';

    return $bag_products;
}

add_shortcode( 'bag_products', 'get_cart_products' );
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Schultz Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For Product link, use following:

```
$product->get_permalink();
```

For Product image, use following:

```
$product->get_image( 'thumbnail' );
```